# Inferring object property from function parameter

Tags: typescript

I defined the function

```js
function test<T>(name: string, value: T) {
    return {[name]: value};
}
```

and VSCode displays the return type as `{[x: string]: T}`. I would like VSCode to complete `foo` after typing

```js
test("foo", "bar").
```

but it doesn't know about `foo` because it isn't in the inferred type.

I've tried

```js
function test<T>(name: string, value: T): {[key: name]: T} {
    return {[name]: value};
}
```

but it complains that `name` is a variable and not a type.

How can I achieve that it takes the value of `name` and uses it as a type?

My use case is a Vue.js mixin, that I've defined with a factory function so I can easily add similar mixins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since I've found the solution:

```js
function bla<T extends string | number | symbol, V>(name: T, value: V) {
  return { [name]: value } as { [K in T]: V };
}
```